Supabase how to prevent updated_at from updating?
I'm using Supabase with a Next.js application to manage articles. I have a requirement where users can "favorite" articles and this action should not update the updated_at timestamp of the article in the database.
// Check if the request is to update only the 'favorited' status
if (body.favorited !== undefined && Object.keys(body).length === 1) {
  // Ensure 'favorited' is a boolean
  if (typeof body.favorited !== "boolean") {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "'favorited' must be a boolean value" },
      { status: 400 }
    );
  }

  // Update the favorited status without affecting the updated_at timestamp
  try {
    const { data, error: updateError } = await supabase
      .from("articles")
      .update({ favorited: body.favorited }) // Update only the favorited status
      .eq("id", id)
      .eq("author_id", user.id)
      .select('*', { head: true }); // Attempt to prevent the updated_at modification

    if (updateError) throw updateError;

    return NextResponse.json({ data }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error updating favorited status:", e);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Something went wrong while updating the favorited status" }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

The issue I'm facing is that even though I'm only updating the favorited field, Supabase automatically updates the updated_at field (which is set to automatically track changes).
My Question:
How can I update only the favorited field without changing the updated_at timestamp in Supabase?
Is there a way to tell Supabase or PostgreSQL not to modify updated_at for specific updates?
Are there any other techniques or best practices to achieve this behavior?
